# Move versus Copy

Tags: linux, bash

I've created a bash script that creates a handful of users then creates a .ssh folder and copies in their authorized_keys file.  I've made sure to set the owner group to the specific user with read-write-execute for the owner only.  The same for the authorized key itself except it only has read-write for the owner permission. I found though that if I use the mv command to move their authorized_keys file from where the script is running to their .ssh folder they aren't able to ssh in however if I use the cp command to copy their file it works just fine.  Any idea why that is?

ls -lh on authorized_keys file before moving:

```
[root@localhost Users]# ls -lh
total 8.0K
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 653 Nov 25 16:31 CreateUserAccounts.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 403 Nov 25 15:13 user1_authorized_keys
```

ls -lhart on .ssh:

```
[root@localhost user1]# ls -lhad .ssh
drwx------. 2 user1 user1 4.0K Nov 25 16:31 .ssh
```

ls -lh on authorized_keys

```
[root@localhost .ssh]# ls -lh
total 4.0K
-rw-------. 1 user1 user1 403 Nov 25 15:13 authorized_keys
```

Comment: Still looks like an owner/permissions problem.  Please post `ls -lh` output for the `authorized_keys` file and `ls -lhad` output for the `.ssh` directory.

Comment: compare the ls -la of the destination files in both cases, and you will understand.

Comment: I think I see what you're talking about, I wasn't paying attention to the number between the permissions and owner name at first but now that I've been enlightened and have read this http://superuser.com/questions/477858/what-does-the-number-after-unix-linux-file-permissions-like-rw-rw-r-1-mea 
I think I see that by moving it the file isn't technically there it's just a link?

Comment: The "." at the end of your authorized_keys and .ssh indicate some selinux settings applied.  What is the output of 'ls -dZ .ssh' and 'ls -Z .ssh/authorized_keys?